# Can i do these in PHP if conditions?

Tags: php, html, mysql

This code had to look in sites table and first check if the typed url is there after that check the status of the url, if status = block then echo telling site is blocked, but apparently what ever the status in the table of a url, is being blocked, shouldn't

```html
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "repute system";
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection_aborted(oid)
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$url = $_POST['url'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM sites " ;

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     $stat = $row['status'];
     if($stat = 'block' && $url == $row['URL'])
     {
       echo "This site is blocked" ;
       die();
      }
    }

    header("Location: $url");
}
?>
```

I use &&, || or and , or in if statements here? and I am also worried about the header statement as i have heard it is quite unstable to use, why is that ? what is its substitute to redirect urls?

Comment: So what is the question now?

Comment: `if($stat = 'block'` you're assigning. You need to compare `if($stat == 'block'` / using 2x equal signs.

Comment: @Rizier123 can i use conditions like && and || in php if conditions, ? if i can , how come i am not able to get what i want ? where am i wrong?

Comment: damn bad question thanks @Fred-ii-

Comment: wow I put a comment and someone sneaks up with an answer lol foiled again!!! classic bunch I'll tell ya.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm putting my comment to an answer: (`22:13:54Z`)

`if($stat = 'block'` you're assigning `$stat` as `block` and will always be TRUE.

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php

You need to compare  `if($stat == 'block'` / using 2x equal signs to check if `$stat` equals `block`.

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: i looked up you website, good work you are doing there !

Comment: @razor That 'ol thing? Thanks; I do much better for my clients. I just whipped that puppy up real quick-like. I hard code 95% of the code that's written, so my hands tend to cramp up from time to time ;-) *Cheers*

Comment: lol i even thought of drooping u a friendly  mail on ur site, but strictly want customers to mail u so, i stopped

Comment: @razor hahaha! I started using bootstrap for a few months now; I should've started using it from its first year of conception. Love it.

Comment: yea use it soon, its not bad but u can do better, there are plenty of templates out there

Comment: @razor Oh, I've got a ton of templates already; that's not what's missing lol :-)

Comment: i cant send u a message.. dont knw why ! i clicked all the tick marks filled everything :p

Comment: @razor it's pretty well guarded with a passphrase.

Comment: so how do i text you?

Comment: @razor you need to enter the passphrase into the right box that's on the splash page.

Comment: mailed you, check it out

Answer (score 1):

```
if($stat = 'block' && $url == $row['URL'])
```

this part does not filter. it should be like this. `$stat=='block'`
when your write like this `$stat = 'block'`
it does not work only for stat='block'